# Single OnChange function on multiple file type

Tags: reactjs, html-input

I have some input with the type of text, which I combined the onChange function to be like so:

```
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

I also have an input with the type of file, which is working too with this

```
const handleFileChange = (e: any) => {
    let selected = e.target.files[0];

    if (selected && types.includes(selected.type)) {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        file: selected,
      });
    } else {
      setFormState({
        ...formState,
        file: null,
      });
      toast({
        status: "error",
        title: "Please select an image file (png or jpg)",
        isClosable: true,
        duration: 4000,
      });
    }
  };
```

How can I combine both into one single function?

Comment: I think you can grab everything into a single function and use a condition on `e.target` to know which input is text or file.

Comment: Please can you do an example, I tried that I got error